# Python: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000

Tags: python, ctypes, access-violation, windowserror

This short function is simply getting the available free space of a storage device, however I am getting the above error when running the code.

The function is:

```
def disk_space1(drive):
    freespace = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    calcspace = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA
    calcspace(drive, ctypes.byref(freespace))
    disk_size = freespace.value
    return disk_size
```

This function worked perfectly until today when it has stopped working for no reason, I haven't changed anything. What's baffling me the most is that the function works properly, if I print out the value of 'freespace' once running it, it has gone and found the correct value, but still gives the error.

What could have caused this issue?

Comment: Consider using pywin32 - it is thin wrapper around Win32 API. I.e.: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file__GetDiskFreeSpaceEx_meth.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling the full function signature which I believe is leading to access violations (due to random memory writes) and errors. The full function signature is (fully documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpDirectoryName,
  _Out_opt_  PULARGE_INTEGER lpFreeBytesAvailable,
  _Out_opt_  PULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
  _Out_opt_  PULARGE_INTEGER lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes
);
```

By changing the function to:

```
def disk_space(drive):
    freespace = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    calcspace = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA
    err = calcspace(drive,
                    ctypes.byref(freespace),
                    None,
                    None)
    assert err != 0, 'calcspace failed'
    disk_size = freespace.value
    return disk_size
```

I was able to run it without intermittent error.

Comment: Well, just pass the `NULL` (i.e. `None`) values to ensure that the stack has allocated zeros for the last two 'optional' parameters: `calcspace(drive, ctypes.byref(freespace), None, None)`. Then the stack won't get corrupted by the cleanup code in `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA` (i.e. x86 stdcall callee cleanup).

Comment: Gonna try this now, I originally took those out since I wasn't using those values for anything, had no problems up until now!

Comment: And it was a success! Thanks for the help guys!