# WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00007FFC00000000

Tags: ctypes, trace32

I am running a program that uses Trace32 and when I run the program I error at the tapAccessShiftRaw method in trace32.py (this comes in the trace32 install) and get the error above. I have been looking around at some different posts related to this issues and tried things that are mentioned in posts such as this: [Python: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631078/python-windowserror-exception-access-violation-reading-0x00000000)
or
["WindowsError: exception: access violation..." - ctypes question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382076/windowserror-exception-access-violation-ctypes-question)

But unfortunately none of these solutions seem to help. I'm running this on Windows 10. Any advice on how I can debug this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: Unless there's an obvious bug in trace32.py, you'll probably need to learn native Windows debugging (e.g. using WinDbg) to investigate the exception. If that's not something you'd care to learn, you can report the bug to the project and wait for someone else to solve the problem.

Comment: so it turns out that if I put a print statement between two array creations in the trace23.py code I do not get the exception Do you happen to know why that may be? I thought that it may have something to do with the fact that there is a buffer that is allocated for prints so I also just trying declaring a dummy array but that failed. Only adding a print does not fail. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just searched for trace32.py in my installation and didn't find it. Are you sure about the name and can you tell me the location inside the T32 system path?

Comment: Also can you be specific with your question. I understand you use the TRACE32 Remote API with Python and have an error using T32_TAPAccessShiftRaw, but not enough to reproduce the problem. An example would be helpful.

Comment: here is the path to the file "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\trace32\trace32.py"

Comment: I was mistaken, this is the trace32 package you need to install to use in python that is giving trouble. Within trace32.py file, there is a function called tapAccessShiftRaw. Within that function, there is some memory being allocated for ibyteBufPtr and obyteBufPtr. Unless I put a statement like "str(int)" in between these two array allocations I get the above error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't think this package is from the TRACE32 installation, I'd rather think that your company added it. To help you it it would be necessary to provide a minimal example which reproduces your error.